# how to decode the json request data valaue in Jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter

I want to decode the data value in JSON request payload. And how do i use counter in the specific decoded value of the data request .

Answer (score 0):

1. The encoded value can be extracted from JSON response into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)
2. Once done you can use JSR223 PostProcessor and [Cipher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) class or [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) library to perform the decoding. The exact implementation will differ depending on the encryption algorithm.